# Copy data within a table and changing values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `USER_OPTIONS`. If I query this table with:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_OPTIONS
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Now, I need to copy the same values (A,1), (B,2), (C,3), etc to the same table but change the `USER_ID` value.
The final result should be something like:

```
2 A 1
2 B 2
2 C 3
2 D 4
2 E 5
2 F 6
3 A 1
3 B 2
3 C 3
3 D 4
3 E 5
3 F 6
```

"Quite simple just add a loop and do it" you might think. But here's the catch...
I need to do this with just one statement. Is there a way to do this? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a plain **INSERT INTO..SELECT**.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO user_options SELECT user_id + 1, code, code_value FROM user_options;

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM user_options;
```

**TEST CASE**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM user_options;

   USER_ID C CODE_VALUE
---------- - ----------
         2 A          1
         2 B          2
         2 C          3
         2 D          4
         2 E          5
         2 F          6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO user_options SELECT user_id + 1, code, code_value FROM user_options;

6 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM user_options ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;

   USER_ID C CODE_VALUE
---------- - ----------
         2 A          1
         2 B          2
         2 C          3
         2 D          4
         2 E          5
         2 F          6
         3 A          1
         3 B          2
         3 C          3
         3 D          4
         3 E          5
         3 F          6

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb, it was quite simple... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Insert into user_options Select 3, code, code_value from user_options;

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the rows using:

```
select u.user_id, uo.code, uo.code_value
from (select 2 as user_id from dual union all select 3 as user_id from dual) u cross join
     user_options uo;
```

If you just want to put them in the same table:

```
insert into user_option(user_id, code, code_value)
    select 3, code, code_value
    from user_options
    where user_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple cross join, As per your scenario you can have following tables

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Userid] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
  );


  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code] (
    [Code]       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Code_Value] INT          NULL
  );
```

Then query like below

```
    select * from userid,code order by Id,Code,Code_Value
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

When you make cartesian join between user_options and table which contains all desired user_id's, you will get the required result

```
select usr.user_id, o.code_,o.code_value from 
user_options o,
(select rownum user_id from dual connect by level <3 ) usr
```

Where "usr" is list of all user_ids. I generated only 1,2 - it can be modified by level condition. Or you can instead join table which contains these user_ids.

Take a look to working example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc096/10